# SharePoint publishing portal v.s. collaboration portal

Tags: publishing-site

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. I want to develop a portal application with login function (logged-in user could have more function to use on the site).

I want to know what are the pros and cons compared of using publishing portal v.s. collaboration portal template?

Answer (score 4):

Publishing portal is typically used for web content management (internet sites), Collaboration portal is typically used for intranets.

Publishing portals contains but a subset of the lists, libraries and subsite templates types you find in Collaboration portal site definition template. Collaboration templates on the other hand contains the lot! You got centralized document repository, site directory, reporting sites etc.

Find a good blog post on the different concepts [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/mossbiz/archive/2009/06/23/clarifications-collaboration-vs-publishing.aspx)

often you will see developers start "from scratch" with a blank site definition and use code to add the needed functionality or use feature stapling to either remove or add functionality from an existing site definition.
See a discussion on that topic [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/171/when-to-use-custom-site-definitions-and-not)

hth
Anders Rask

Comment: I have nothing to add :)

Comment: Do you mean I should always use collaboration portal? Any performance comparisons?

Comment: From your first link, it is mentioned -- "Publishing needs heavy branding, high performance read-only access (caching), staging and deployment, while Collaboration needs clear functionality, ease of engagement, consistency between sites and high performance read/write access (no caching, fast servers)." -- so, seems performance is worse for collaboration portal is most operations are read for my portal (because of no cache)?

Comment: This all depends on how you use them. You wont be able to achieve much with OOTB caching if you got login (as you mention). Using output cache with login would mean that certain user specific controls would be cached (eg welcome menu could show up with wrong user name). More personalization means less caching and hence it will be more challenging to achieve good performance. So even if you went for publishing (which by the very little you specify, sounds like a good bet) you still would need to take into considerations that you had logged in users, when setting up caching.

Answer (score 1):

If there are features of one template that you like, you can always add it to the other one. For example, if you start with the Collaboration template, you can activate the Publishing infrastructure and have a subsite in the collaboration portal set up for managing pages using the web content management functionality.

Comment: I am setting up a portal for my company facing internet. Any recommendations for which one to use? Any performance comparisons?